# SMS Composer SketchFlow Mock

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, sketchflow

Is there an SMS Composer screen Mock in Expression Blend SketchFlow for Windows Phone? Or should I build one on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll just need to make one of your own, but there's not a lot to that view.